# Uploading picture camera file to absolute path folder

Tags: coldfusion

I'm new to ColdFusion and was trying to attempt a simple process to where you take a picture of something with your IOS camera device and it sends it to a drive on your computer in a absolute path temporary folder. I don't know if this is the right approach to doing this?

However, when I hit submit it returns a fatal error I'm not sure why here is what I attempted. Also, when i tested to see if the uploadfile was set but it says it isn't and yet it is in the name field?

**test.cfm**

```
<form name="uploadform" action="testaction.cfm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="cameraInput" name="uploadfile">
<input type="submit" name="uploadsubmit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

**testaction.cfm**

```
 <cfif isDefined("form.uploadfile")>
<cffile
action = "upload"
fileField= "uploadfile"
destination= "T:\cftest"
nameConflict= "overwrite">
<cfelse>
<form name="uploadform" action="test.cfm" method="POST" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="cameraInput" 
name="uploadfile">
    <input type="submit" name="uploadsubmit" value="Upload">
</form> 
</cfif>
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: What error are you getting? There is going to be an error in application.log and more detailed error in exception.log.

Comment: Maybe the Coldfusion process is not allowed to access remote drive t:

Comment: One second I'm trying to give you guys the error. First, trying to figure out how to enable debugging.

Comment: Assuming you are working on a Dev box, log into the CF Admin. Under *Debugging & Logging > Debug Output Settings*, check the *Enable Robust Exception Information* box. You could also just a) wrap the code in a cftry/cfcatch and dump the error in the cfcatch block, ie `<cfdump var="#cfcatch#>` OR b) check the `{cf_root_direc}\logs\exception.log` file like WilGeno mentioned.